# Getting DNS error while setup samba4 on ubuntu server

Tags: samba

We have installed samba4 on ubuntu 18.04 server and we are getting DNS error

[Issue in DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTtpf.png)

Please find the /etc/resolv.conf file

[resolv.conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGKZv.png)

Please find the /etc/samba/smb.conf

[smb.conf file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXCTJ.png)

Please help me to resolve the issue

Thanks

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should allow the trafic in firewall with these :

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 135 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 135 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 135 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 135 -j ACCEPT
```

tho if you dont add

```
browseable = yes
```

you may not see the shared files